# Integrate Spring Cloud Brixton.M1 into Spring Boot 1.2.6 application?

Tags: spring, maven-2, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-cloud

It seems that i am missing something in my current setup of my pom.xml. Currently i have a Spring Boot application configured with a starter.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Now that i want to  integrate this application with Spring Cloud Brixton.M1. According to the documentation i need to add the follow block:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories> 
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.M1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And add for example Spring Cloud Turbine AMQP.
        
            org.springframework.cloud
            spring-cloud-starter-turbine-amqp

I also annotated the Spring Boot start class with:

> @EnableTurbineAmqp

But now when i start the application i get the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forInstance(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;

It seems that there are 2 versions of Spring Core on the classpath which have a conflict. Is there a prefered way of excluding one or they other?

Comment: Spring Cloud depends on Spring 4.2, while Spring Boot 1.2 depends on Spring 4.1. You can simply add `spring.version` as property yo your pom and set it to `4.2.1.RELEASE` but this might break certain Spring Boot features (although I expect that it would simply work).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Brixton M1 requires Spring Boot 1.3.x